# Angular2+ need routerLinkActive type solution for optional parameters

Tags: angular

I'm struggling with setting the active flag on a link that matches an optional param.

Here are my routes:

```
{ path: 'clients', component: ClientListComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
{ path: 'clients/:id', component: ClientDetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard] },
```

The first is the full list, the second is the detail for the selected `id`. (So I'd rather not try to use a required param in the url)

I have 2 links on the `ClientListComponent` that represent "Active only" (default) and "All" filters.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/clients']" ...
<a [routerLink]="['/clients', {showAll: 'true'}]" ...
```

Resulting in the URLs:

```
/clients
/clients;showAll=true
```

Any suggestions on how I could wire up the active class for these? The standard `routerLinkActive` [ignores optional parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to route changes, and then use a flag to mark the route alongside `[ngClass]`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  clientFlag = true;
  showAllFlag = true;

  constructor(
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe( (e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (e.url === '/clients') {
            this.clientFlag = true;
            this.showAllFlag = false;
        } else {
            this.clientFlag = false;
            this.showAllFlag = true;
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

and in your html template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/clients']" [ngClass]="{'custom-class': clientFlag}" ...
<a [routerLink]="['/clients', {showAll: 'true'}]" [ngClass]="{'custom-class-2': showAllFlag}" ...
```

There are ways to make this sort of 'route checking' more elegant (single object for the flag, higher level route name checking, etc), but this should give the general form of how you can quickly and efficiently implement custom route checking (for your case of a substitute for [`[routerLinkActive]`](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive).

Comment: I ended up using your answer as a starting point, and used the `DefaultUrlSerializer` to help me turn the `e.url` in the event into an object that I can better compare against my routes.